# css: applying text-align and appending text in a single rule

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I am looking to present a set of properties. key: val type-of-thing. Not knowing any better, I am laying it out in a table.

The following css:

```css
table.properties td:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}

table.properties td:first-child::after {
  content: ":";
}
```

aligns the text in the 1st column (the keys) to the right, then appends a semicolon.

Is there a way to express that in a more concise way? Like in a single rule? Or maybe such presentation is better done in another manner altogether?

Appreciate a tip!